# Execute SSH command on Ubuntu from C#

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, ssh

I want to execute a SSH command from an ASP.NET application. I found Tamir.SharpSsh. In my case the Ubuntu server only allows key based login so i am using the following code but that throws a connection timeout error. my code is as follows

```
string cmd = "cd projects/test;sudo python parallel.py";
SshExec sshexec = new SshExec("IP Address", "", "");
sshexec.AddIdentityFile(Server.MapPath("~/assets/mykey-openssh"), "key-phrase");
sshexec.Connect();
sshexec.RunCommand(cmd);
```

Appreciate if someone can point me in the correct direction.